# How to zip 2 lists but 1 list acts as a single unit?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have

```
a = [5,3,7] 
b = [9,4]
```

I want

```
c = [5,3,7,9,5,3,7,4]
```

Preferably a 1 liner solution that returns the desired output. List has to be flat.

I have tried the following:

`[i if j==0 else j for i in [7,4] for j in [5,3,7,0]]`

But am wondering if there is an even shorter/cleaner solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure whether the following is cleaner, but here's an option:

```py
a = [5,3,7]
b = [9,4]

output = [x for y in b for x in [*a, y]]
print(output) # [5, 3, 7, 9, 5, 3, 7, 4]
```

At least it is better than the original code in that it allows for `a` to have `0` (or any value) as its element.

Comment: You are creating extra list which are not needed, you could rewrite as append: 
output = [x for y in b for x in a+[y]]